# ¿Cual es el equivalente de private lateinit var de kotlin en Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

estoy desarrollando una pequeña app para un trabajo de clase pero la explicación viene en Kotlin y yo tengo que usar Java. Mi problema es que no se como transpasar el código de un lenguaje a otro. Adjunto el código Kotlin.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var txtNombre : EditText
private lateinit var btnAceptar : Button
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //Obtenemos una referencia a los controles de la interfaz
    txtNombre = findViewById(R.id.txtNombre)
    btnAceptar = findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar)
    btnAceptar.setOnClickListener {
        //Creamos el Intent
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SaludoActivity::class.java)
        //Añadimos al intent la información a pasar entre actividades
        intent.putExtra("NOMBRE", txtNombre.text.toString())
        //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Mi problema principal es traducir los lateinit var y demás sintaxis de Kotlin a Java. Espero haberme explicado bien. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El equivalente sería `private EditText txtNombre;`

Comment: y el setOnClickListener con su interior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Android Studio puedes convertir el código Kotlin a Java, desde el menú ve a la opción `Tools` > `Kotlin` > `Show Kotlin Bytecode`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Da clic en el botón <kbd>Decompile</kbd> y se mostrará código Java, puedes usarlo como base para tu conversión de Kotlin a Java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Con respecto a la declaración de la variable usando `lateinit` en Kotlin:

```
private lateinit var txtNombre : EditText
```

`lateinit` significa inicialización tardía y no se asignará memoria hasta que se inicialice, en Java no existe ya que puedes realizar la inicialización posteriormente pero tu debes garantizar la inicialización antes de usarla.
esta sería la versión Java:

```
 private EditText txtNombre;
```

Con respecto al `Intent` en Kotlin:

```
    //Creamos el Intent
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SaludoActivity::class.java)
    //Añadimos al intent la información a pasar entre actividades
    intent.putExtra("NOMBRE", txtNombre.text.toString())
    //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
    startActivity(intent)
```

esta sería la versión Java:

```
    //Creamos el Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaludoActivity.class);
    //Añadimos al intent la información a pasar entre actividades
    intent.putExtra("NOMBRE", txtNombre.getText().toString())
    //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
    startActivity(intent)
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText txtNombre;
  private Button btnAceptar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Obtenemos una referencia a los controles de la interfaz
        txtNombre = findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        btnAceptar = findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);


     btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creamos el Intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaludoActivity.class);
                //Añadimos al intent la información a pasar entre actividades
                intent.putExtra("NOMBRE", txtNombre.getText().toString())
                //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        });

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Así quedaría la conversión de kotlin a java, si lo analizas detalladamente, notarás que la sintaxis es similar

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText txtNombre;
  private Button btnAceptar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Obtenemos una referencia a los controles de la interfaz
        txtNombre = findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        btnAceptar = findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);


     btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaludoActivity.class);
                //Añadimos al intent la información a pasar entre actividades
                intent.putExtra("NOMBRE", txtNombre.getText().toString())
                //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        });

}

}
```